# xlrd error message

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm trying to use `xlrd` to manipulate an `.xls` file as follows:

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('6h.xls')
```

And I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/wayne-szalinsky/virt_env/virt_env/virt2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 435, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,

  File "/home/wayne-szalinsky/virt_env/virt_env/virt2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 91, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)

  File "/home/wayne-szalinsky/virt_env/virt_env/virt2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1230, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])

  File "/home/wayne-szalinsky/virt_env/virt_env/virt2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1224, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '<?xml ve'
```

Comment: Are you certain that `6h.xls` *is* a valid Excel file? Where did it come from, and have you tried opening it in Excel?

Comment: What version of xlrd are you running?  Can you enter the following after you import xlrd:  xlrd.__VERSION__

Answer (score 2):

Your file is apparently an XML file with an incorrect filename extension of `.xls`. If you wish to open it as an Excel file, it  must first be saved as an Excel file, not just named like one.

You might be able to open it in a text editor, observe how the XML document is laid out, and write your code to parse the XML instead of using xlrd.

Comment: this is absolutely a great answer!